# File handling using Play framework

Tags: jquery, ajax, scala, playframework-2.0

I need to upload a file from client side and manipulate it in server side. After the manipulation, It(file) has to be displayed in the same webpage without reloading the whole page. I am using Scala in Play framework 2.X, with separate html,js scripts. 
File types-  .txt .xml .html

,etc

I already tried it using forms and uploaded the file. The manipulated output is displayed in next page.

Edit:1

HTML

```
<form class = "class1" id="myForm1" action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" size="60" id= "fileUpload1" name="fileUpload1">
    <input type="submit" id ="ajaxCallUpload1" value="Validate">
</form>
```

JS

```
var form = document.getElementById('fileUpload1');
var uploadButton = document.getElementById('ajaxCallUpload1');
var outputMessage = document.getElementById('message1');

form.onsubmit = function(event){
event.preventDefault();
uploadButton.innerHTML= "Uploading.... "
}
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append('file',form)
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
}
xhr.open('POST','/upload',true);
xhr.onload = function(){
if (xhr.status === 200){
uploadButton.innerHTML = 'Uploaded';
}
else{
alert('An error occurred!')
}
};
xhr.send(formdata)
```

Controller

```
def upload = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { request =>
    request.body.file("fileUpload1").map { file =>
    //file manupulation
  Ok( output response)
    }.getOrElse {
      Ok("Error during uploading")
  }}
```

I am getting error in form.onsubmit() and the output is alert-Error during uploading(when the page gets loaded). 
After the uploading the file i am getting output in another  page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for help  @aleck.
I figured out and it worked perfectly.

HTML

```
    <form id="myForm" >
        <input  type="file" size="60" id ="fileUpload" name="fileUpload">
        <input type="button" id ="ajaxCallUpload2" onclick= "extract(this)" value="Extract">
    </form>

 <div id="response" ><pre id="message"></pre></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function extract(){
$("#message").empty();
var file = $("#fileUpload").get(0).files[0];
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file',file);
console.log("file appended")
$.ajax({
        url: '/extract',
        type: 'POST',
        data:  formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) {
        console.log(data)
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=data;
        },
        error: function () {
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="Oops! Invalid file.";
        }
    });
}
```

Controller

```
def extract = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { request =>
    val file = request.body.file("file").get
      //manipulation
        Ok(/*manipulated result*/)}
      }
```

Comment: Well done mate, sorry wasn't able to help time-wise.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do:
- from client side - an Ajax post request to upload the file;
- from server side - receive the file, do whatever required and return file’s URL;
- from client side - on response - use server response (the URL) to show the file however you want it.

Comment: any reason for not using jQuery? asking since you have tagged it in the question

Comment: Open to jQuery. Please Do suggest some snippets.